# Navigating to subpage from multiple locations

Tags: mobile, navigation, android, mobile-application, ios

Let's assume the following Navigation Hierarchy:

---

RootPage1

-> SubPage1

RootPage2

RootPage3

---

- All RootPages are accessible from the NavBar.
- RootPage1 has a button that navigates the user to SubPage1.
- SubPage1 is a sub page with the navigation visible (so no modal/hidden  navigation).

We want to direct the user from RootPage3 to SubPage1.

Since navigation is visible on SubPage1:

1. *If the SubPage1 is accessed from RootPage3, should we highlight the RootPage3 Navigation icon, or the RootPage1 navigation icon?*
2. *By navigating to SubPage1 from RootPage3, does the user enter the RootPage1 Hierarchy?*

Answer (score 1):

Looking from the other perspective, to be specific, the code perspective, this page will be placed in one particular folder and have one URL, but can be accessed by many links and buttons within the website.

So in your case, you need to make a definition for this page, to which RootPage is it more related. If it's more related to RootPage1, then RootPage1 is always the parent for the SubPage1. So to answer your questions:

1. No, highlighting the menu item should not depend on the source you came from. Otherwise, from the user point of view, you have two pages with the exact same content, and then questions appear "is it up to date?" or "I am sure this page was somewhere else". It can only confuse the user if he sees different breadcrumbs / different URL for the same page depending on the source.
2. Yes, whenever you link the user from any other RootPage to the SubPage1, the user goes inside RootPage1 hierarchy, because this is the logical place for the SubPage1.

Hope it helps, but happy to dig deeper if you need clarification :)